# AWS CodeCommit Project Structure

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, amazon-web-services, maven

I am trying to create an Eclipse springboot project under a CodeCommit repository and have a question on the structure. Say I have a project SpringBootSample which includes eclipse .project and other folders like src, pom.xml underneath. When I add it to the CodeCommit repository the project directory gets created on the branch which is OK. However, I am wondering where to place the buildspec.yml file as it needs to be at the root. Also how can i reference the Maven file underneath the project directory? Is this allowed or do i need to upload the files at the root level?

Thank you in advance!

Best
SG

Answer (score 0):

"If you include a buildspec as part of the source code, by default, the buildspec file must be named buildspec.yml and placed in the root of your source directory. " [source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html)

Where you place the pom.xml and remaining files is up to you, as long as you reference them properly in the buildspec.yml.

With pom.xml at the root level:

```
phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - mvn clean install
```

With pom.xml in a subfolder called `my-project`:

```
phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - (cd my-project && mvn clean install)
```

Comment: Thank you Micheal, Does this mean the buildspec.yml has to be at the root of the branch? In that case, how can i have multiple buildspec.yml files one per project? if the buildspec.yml is inside the project folder, i get an error saying it should be at the root. Thank you